# Refacturação de consulta à base de dados com multiplos FIND_IN_SET()

Tags: mysql, sql-select, refatoração, mysql-find-in-set

Tenho a seguinte consulta para localizar tópicos relacionados por um conjunto de ID's que não sejam o tópico a ser visualizado:

```sql
SELECT
    press.image,
    press_i18n.title,
    press_i18n.slug
FROM press
INNER JOIN press_i18n ON (
    press.press_id = press_i18n.press_id
)
WHERE press.ocult_from_site = 'no'
AND press.status = 'active'
AND press_i18n.i18n_id = 'por'
AND (
    FIND_IN_SET (1326, REPLACE(press.tag_id, ";", ","))
    OR
    FIND_IN_SET (77, REPLACE(press.tag_id, ";", ","))
)
AND press_i18n.slug != 'bubu-tem-muito-sono'
ORDER by press.publish_date DESC
```

> Showing rows 0 - 7 (8 total, Query took 0.0047 sec)

A consulta conforme o exemplo em cima está a receber dois ID's, mas se receber vinte, vai-se tornar um pouco repetitiva.

Além disso, a função [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) foi desenhada para trabalhar com `,` mas está a ser neste exemplo utilizada para localizar valores separados por `;`.

## Pergunta

Como optimizar a consulta de forma a garantir o correcto desempenho da mesma à medida que a tabela vai enchendo e/ou o número de ID's a localizar vai aumentando?

```sql
-- ...
AND (
    FIND_IN_SET (1326, REPLACE(press.tag_id, ";", ","))
    OR
    FIND_IN_SET (77, REPLACE(press.tag_id, ";", ","))
    OR
    FIND_IN_SET (10545, REPLACE(press.tag_id, ";", ","))
    OR
    FIND_IN_SET (43256, REPLACE(press.tag_id, ";", ","))
    OR
    FIND_IN_SET (1234567, REPLACE(press.tag_id, ";", ","))
    OR
    FIND_IN_SET (7654321, REPLACE(press.tag_id, ";", ","))
)
-- ...
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3ec5) para ajudar nos testes, com a estrutura mínima para o exemplo em dado.

Comment: Vale mexer na estrutura do banco, ou só na query?

Comment: Vale tudo, estrutura optimizada e/ou consulta optimizada, o importante é garantir a performance com o passar do tempo. @bfavaretto

Answer (score 2):

Seria interessante você normalizar o banco, criando uma tabela de relacionamento entre `press` e `tags`. A coluna `press.tag_id` seria eliminada, e a tabela de relacionamento `press_tags` ficaria com esta cara:

```
press_id   tag_id
------------------
       1     1326
       1       77
       1    10545
```

Você faz um `JOIN` com essa tabela no corpo da query:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN press_tags
ON press_tag.press_id = press.id
```

Aí todo o bloco com os `FIND_IN_SET` pode ser substituído por:

```
AND press_tags.tag_id IN(1326, 77, 10545)
```

Tudo junto:

```
SELECT
    press.image,
    press_i18n.title,
    press_i18n.slug
FROM press
INNER JOIN press_i18n ON (
    press.press_id = press_i18n.press_id
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN press_tags ON (
    press_tag.press_id = press.id
    -- ou 
    -- press_tag.press_id = press.press_id
    -- (o que fizer mais sentido no seu banco)
)
WHERE press.ocult_from_site = 'no'
AND press.status = 'active'
AND press_i18n.i18n_id = 'por'
AND press_tags.tag_id IN(1326, 77, 10545)
AND press_i18n.slug != 'bubu-tem-muito-sono'
ORDER by press.publish_date DESC
```

Você deve precisar também de um índice em `tag_id` nessa tabela de relacionamento. Pode querer também uma coluna `id` (PK com auto increment), alguns frameworks exigem isso para poder deletar linhas.